# Scroll down Google Maps to show all items

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

how to Scroll down Google Maps to show all items and return to the first item??
I tried more than one using Selenium and Google Drive 109.0.5414.74/ .
All attempts were unsuccessful.
The scroll down only one centimeter and not to the last element. I don't know what the problem is.

[image]
[image]

my try

`  foreach (var item in driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='QA0Szd']/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]")))
{

```
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='QA0Szd']/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]")).Click();
            Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
            actions.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.PageDown).Build().Perform();
         
        }
```

`